# Generic response to Homework Questions

Tags: discussion, site-activity

I thought I'd post my blurb on responding to homework questions which violate site policy.

If you see any, just post this as a comment, usually the user will edit their question.

> Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where we require that you show some work before an answer is provided. More on this topic here:`https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions`

the user in question shows his work using *only* images an appropriate response is:

> Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where users must demonstrate effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site. Using only images as proof of work is insufficient. for more details see:`https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions`

If the community helps, we can improve question quality without newer users undergrad students.

If anyone has a better blurb or idea, please post.

Comment: I think its good

Answer (score 3):

I dare propose a more succinct formulation as follows:

> Welcome to Economics SE! Please note that we do have a [policy on homework questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/) that requires you to demonstrate reasonable effort, which includes your own attempt(s) at a solution as well as properly formatting the post using [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [MathJax](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1417).

Copy-and-paste-friendly version:

> `Welcome to Economics SE! Please note that we do have a [policy on homework questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/) that requires you to demonstrate reasonable effort, which includes your own attempt(s) at a solution as well as properly formatting the post using [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [MathJax](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1417).`

Comment: I think you can just add it as a third option to all generic responses. This new generic response does not change site policy, and we already have 2 versions so this can be third  one. There is nothing wrong as far as I see with wording here so you can just directly add it there in my opinion https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/all-generic-responses