# Should we add automatic comment under homework questions?

Tags: feature-request, homework

Presently when user votes to close question as a duplicate an automatic comment is generated below with message "Does this answer your question?" with link provided. I think that having similar automated comment for homework questions could be also beneficial because:

1. It sometimes takes few days for homework questions to get closed. These homework questions are usually made by new users who might not notice single close vote or understand it as they might not be familiar with how the site works - a comment with [the generic response](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/generic-response-to-homework-questions) might give the user information about what is wrong with the question right away in a way that is clear even to someone who never visited any stack before. Furthermore, it gives the user chance to change the question before it gets closed in the first place.
2. Even though users who vote to close are free to copy-paste this generic response, presently it takes extra effort to do so. User has to first find the generic response, some might not even know we have one, then it has to be copied and what even worse this only works on desktop because on phone app copy-pasting from different SE pages does not work (I am not sure if this is bug or not or if it affects all devices). As a result this generic response is rarely used.
3. Such automated answer would give information not just to the person asking it but also to the new users who might not know the site's culture and waste time providing solution and encouraging such practice (like [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39411/time-value-of-money-cash-flow-diagram)). This would not be an issue if questions would get closed promptly but as mentioned above sometimes it can take considerable time for that to happen here.

Would adding such feature be feasible and do other users here agree it would be desirable to have it?

Comment: "*users who vote to close are free to copy-paste this generic response*" Not to mention you have to copy the homework FAQ link separately.