# Where should the "MathJax help" link (on the Editing Help page for our community) point to?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax, hyperlinks

One of the community managers at Stack Exchange has pointed out that in the editing-help page for our site, [which you can find by clicking here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/editing-help), there is a section on LaTeX, which at the bottom has a MathJax help link that defaults to [this location here](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/).

However, this link is customizable for any community that has MathJax enabled. The Math Stack was given as an example, where they created their own meta post for showcasing how to use MathJax, [which you can find here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

The question we have for the community, then, is:
**Where should our MathJax help link point to?**

- Should we create a meta post explaining MathJax and then point our
  link there?
- Should it point to some other useful resource?
- Some communities also just choose to link to the Math StackExchange's
  post that I linked above.

We would like your feedback. When we have an agreeable idea within the community, we will add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to alert the CMs so they can make the change. Personally, I think it'd be great to move away from the default link, but we would like to hear from the community.

Comment: It looks like this site already has an FAQ here about MathJax (albeit apparently copied from the Math Meta post): [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1417/14215). So that could be a candidate for option #1.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that the way MathJax works within Econ SE and in Maths SE (and indeed in any other SE site) is exactly the same?  I have always assumed this is the case, but it would be useful to be sure on this point before deciding the most appropriate help link.

Comment: @AdamBailey: Yes, MathJax works largely identically network-wide – with the exception of, e.g., Chemistry SE, where the mhchem extension for MathJax is also enabled.

Comment: @Kitsune Cavalry: Has there been any attention/interest from the community in updating this link? If not, you may also want to add the [featured] tag to this post to increase the visibility of the discussion and get more people to weigh in.

Comment: Folks can can weigh in by posting an answer below, indicating what they think the link should be updated to point to and why, and the rest of the community can vote on those answers. (For instance, do y'all want to make any improvements to the post I linked above, and then update the "MathJax help" link to point there? If so, make those updates and suggest it in an answer.)  Once the community agrees on what URL this link should point to, the mods can [escalate the request for staff attention by adding the \[status-review\] tag to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251).

Comment: @V2Blast I don't think there is much interest in updating the link from what I can tell. I think it is fine to point our link to the Math SE's link for now, and then we can reevaluate this question again in the future.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry: I'd suggest posting that idea as an answer for now, at least, so that the community can weigh in by voting on it. (If anyone has a better suggestion, they can post a separate answer with their own suggestion for what the link should point to.)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to link to the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) post here on Economics Meta; it's currently just copied from the original Math Meta post, but can be updated now or in the future to include guidance that's specifically relevant to this community.

---

(To the community: please vote on the answers here to indicate your preference; if you want to propose a different option instead, feel free to do so in a new answer!)

Comment: The "MathJax help" link on Economics.SE (and this Meta site) has been changed to point to [this Economics Meta post](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), per this suggestion. Let us know if you encounter any problems!

Answer (score 0):

The option of least resistance that is also more than sufficient is to use the Math SE's good resource on MathJax, rather than try to reinvent the wheel.

The link in question [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).